# Timeline page should have a "return to the question" link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, timeline

While reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59770743/12511801), I noticed the "Timeline" button (*below the downvote button*) and, once I click the Timeline button, I did check the changes made in the question, but, the Timeline page doesn't have a "return to the question" link - as the link that appears once a question/answer is edited.

The Timeline page should have a "return to the question" link, due that - if you press the back button in your browser (and, *depending the clicks you might done*), the browser history will return to such actions and not to the actual question.

Comment: Clicking [here](https://i.imgur.com/8X8tYuP.png) while on the timeline page will take you back to the question.

Comment: @Spevacus You mean like "clicking on the question" takes you to the question?

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Maaaaybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every timeline of a question has, near the top and above the (new) *Event filters*, a line starting with "Timeline for ...". It is followed by the question title, which can be used to ... ***return*** to the question. And even though it doesn't have a link title like *Return to question*, it should be obvious what will happen if you use that link ... i.e *return to the question*.

Bonus: for the timeline of an answer, there is a similar link (with the question title as the link title). If you use that link you are returned to the answer that the timeline is about. What else could one want ...