# Timeline page should make it easy to go to specific answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, hyperlinks, timeline

I was looking at the [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/398537/timeline) of [What can we do to encourage downvoting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting) on Meta.SO. This is a big question with lots of answers. In the timeline I saw an answer that I was interested in reading because it had 5 upvotes.

[image]

To actually read this answer I had to click on the link to the timeline of the answer and then click on the question title:
[image]

My feature request is to:

- Add a direct link to answers on the question timeline. Possible candidates:

  - The timestamp. This would be similar to timestamp link on comments or in the question list, which also link to the post. Currently this timestamp links to the timeline list with the event on top, which may also be useful, but possibly that link could be moved somewhere else.
  - The <kbd>answer</kbd> label (is currently not a link)
  - A new column
- On the page with the answer timeline make more clear that the post is an answer, to hint that the title link will take you to the answer (now I just thought it would take me to the question, like a normal question title link)

  - For example "Timeline for answer to X" on top of the page (instead of "Timeline for X" what it is now)
- Also on the answer timeline add a link in the list, cf. [Timeline page should have a "return to the question" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342329/timeline-page-should-have-a-return-to-the-question-link). That related question was downvoted, but I thought the lack of discoverability both in the situation described there as in the situation described in the current question deserves some attention.
- Make the contrast between normal text and (visited) link text a bit bigger, now it is hard to see that the title is a link (maybe this point is a bit Meta.SO specific, although link colors on SE are somewhat unclear/counterintuitive for many sites in my opinion)

This would be particularly helpful for bigger questions, where it is difficult to just go back to the question from the question timeline and try to find the answer that you want to see between dozens of other answers.

Comment: There's even no need for a new column for linking the answers. They can have the same format as the "added" link for comments or "history" for editing a post, [for example][https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UAap.png]. Currently, `added` links directly to the comment. And `history` is a toggle to show/hide the content directly in the timeline.